# Program Counter's Increment Won't Work

Tags: vhdl, counter, increment

Everything works but the increment function. It can increment from 0 to 1, 1 to 2, and then from 2 it goes to "1111111111". I'm stumped.

Variables:

D_IN: Data in

PC_OE: Active high. Drives PC_TRI output.

PC_LD: Active high synchronously loads D_IN into PC.

PC_INC: Active high synchronously increments value in PC.

RST: Active high asyncronous reset.

PC_COUNT: Current value in PC. Address.

PC_TRI: Current value in the PC under tri-state control. When PC_OE = '1', PC_TRI <= 
PC_COUNT, else high impedance.

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL; 


entity ProgramCounter is
    Port ( D_IN : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);

           PC_OE : in  STD_LOGIC;

           PC_LD : in  STD_LOGIC;

           PC_INC : in  STD_LOGIC;

           RST : in  STD_LOGIC;

           CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;

           PC_COUNT : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);

           PC_TRI : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0));


end ProgramCounter;

architecture Behavioral of ProgramCounter is

signal s_COUNT : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);

begin

s_COUNT <= "0000000000";

proc: process(RST, CLK, PC_LD, D_IN, s_COUNT, PC_INC, PC_OE)
begin

    if  (RST = '1') then
        s_COUNT <= "0000000000";
    elsif (rising_edge(CLK)) then

        if (PC_LD = '1') then
            s_COUNT <= D_IN;
        elsif (PC_INC = '1') then
            s_COUNT <= s_COUNT + 1;
        else
      end if;

    else
    end if;

if (PC_OE = '1') then
    PC_TRI <= s_COUNT;
else
    PC_TRI <= "ZZZZZZZZZZ";
end if;

PC_COUNT <= s_COUNT;

end process proc;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Are you sure PC_LD isn't mistakenly set?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I'm using a simulator to test it. It says PC_LD is '0'. What's weird is that none of the data I'm putting in is "1111111111". I have no idea where it's getting that value.

Comment: In the architecture body there's a concurrent assignment of `"0000000000"` to `s_count`. There's an additional driver in process `proc`. The "+" will propagate `'X'`s after resolving `s_count`s(0),'0' and `1`. Is your test case capable of reproducing your symptoms?

Comment: It looks like you wanted to do `s_COUNT <= "0000000000";` to set an initial value, but a concurrent statement like that will cause conflicts. The correct way to set an initial value is in your signal declaration like this: `signal s_COUNT : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0) := "0000000000";` or `signal s_COUNT : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0) := (others => '0');`.

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of QuantumRipple is very useful

```
begin
--s_COUNT <= "0000000000";
...
```

I tried to comment such line and it worked. 
Try to do this, and make RST before start to count

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way and let me know, i corrected your code but I can't try it :

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL; 


entity ProgramCounter is
    Port ( D_IN : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);

           PC_OE : in  STD_LOGIC;

           PC_LD : in  STD_LOGIC;

           PC_INC : in  STD_LOGIC;

           RST : in  STD_LOGIC;

           CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;

           PC_COUNT : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);

           PC_TRI : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0));


end ProgramCounter;

architecture Behavioral of ProgramCounter is

signal s_COUNT : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);

begin

proc: process(RST, CLK)
begin

    if  (RST = '1') then
        s_COUNT <= "0000000000";
    elsif (rising_edge(CLK)) then

        if (PC_LD = '1') then
            s_COUNT <= D_IN;
        elsif (PC_INC = '1') then
            s_COUNT <= s_COUNT + 1;
        else
      end if;

    else
    end if;
end process;

PC_TRI <= s_COUNT when (PC_OE = '1') else (others => 'Z');
PC_COUNT <= s_COUNT;



end Behavioral;
```

Comment: THe second driver contributing to `s_count` would cause it to go from `"0000000000"` to `"0000000000X"` in the first increment, and `"XXXXXXXXXX"` in the next due to std_logic_1164's resolution function. This doesn't match the symptoms described "...from 0 to 1, 1 to 2, and then from 2 it goes to "1111111111"."