# How to assign value of signal to out port?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, synthesis

I have been trying to assign a value of a signal to an out port. I'm getting the proper output of seconds for the signal when I simulate the design but as soon as I assign the value of signal to out port it gives me a WARNING. This warning is pasted below. I have tried using the signal and outport both keeping `std_logic` but still get the same error.

I believe one from you will have my answer.

Thanks in advance.

> FF/Latch has a constant value of 0 in block . 
>           This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process. WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch has a constant value of 0 in block . 
>           This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process. WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch has a constant value of 0 in block . 
>           This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process. WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch has a constant value of 0 in block . 
>           This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process. WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch has a constant value of 0 in block . 
>           This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process. WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch has a constant value of 0 in block . 
>           This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process. WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch has a constant value of 0 in block . 
>           This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process. WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch has a constant value of 0 in block . 
>           This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.

Here's my code!

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

    entity clock is
       port ( CLKin: in std_logic;
              CLKout: out std_logic);
    end clock;

    architecture arch of clock is

      signal counter: integer:=0;
      signal temp : std_logic := '1';

    begin

      process(CLKin,counter,temp)
      begin
        if(CLKin'event and CLKin='1') then
          counter <=counter+1;
          if (counter = 50000000) then
            temp <= NOT temp; 
            counter<=0;
            CLKout <= temp;
          end if;
        end if;
      end process;
    end arch;
```

Comment: Your question lacks sufficient information. Can you post your code, at least?

Comment: The warning is indicative that your assignments are going to crap somewhere (essentially the latches are being optimized out).

Comment: For an example of a successful question with the same warnings, see [VHDL Synthesis - FF/Latch Constant Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087307/vhdl-synthesis-ff-latch-constant-value). Note the declaration of the variable (in that case), an integer wasn't constrained causing all the trimming. VHDL code is actually needed for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was happend because of your:

```
signal counter: integer:=0;
signal temp : std_logic := '1';
```

The initial values ignored during synthesis

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Serhii Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135823/program-counters-increment-wont-work/26197121#26197121) and this is also what the tool is trying to warn you about. Initial statements do not synthesize², and a proper version of your code used for synthesis would have to incorporate a reset signal that had this effect.
So you're looking for something like:

```
    IF reset='0' THEN
        -- Reset the counter and assign initial values
        signal counter <= 0;
        signal temp <= '1';
    ELSIF  rising_edge(clk) THEN
        -- do the actual processing
    END IF;
```

..at the beginning of your process.

² i.e. it's solely meant for simulation and test purposes and thus get's ignored by most synthesis tools.